# Read Excel File Using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to save each Row of an excel file in a list using openpyxl.

```
wb = load_workbook('Shop.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

l = []

a_column = ws['A']
b_column = ws['B']

for x in range(len(a_column)):
    l.append([a_column[x].value, b_column[x].value])

print(l)
```

Output: `[[A1, B1], [A2, B2]]`

It works but does anyone know a better way?

The list, for example, only works through the length of A.

Comment: I rolled back your edit since the last line actually makes this question clear. Sorry for the earlier comment that suggested otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one line with `ws.iter_rows()`

```py
l = [row for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=2, values_only=True)]
```

Good to note that the maximum column length openpyxl finds in Excel can be influenced by cells containing `None` below where you think your data ends.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
a_values = [cell.value for cell in a_column]
b_values = [cell.value for cell in b_column]

list(itertools.zip_longest(a_values, b_values))
#=> [('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A3', 'B3'), (None, 'B4'), (None, 'B5')]
```

Comment: `ws.iter_rows()` or `ws.iter_cols()` is the way to do this.

Comment: @CharlieClark, thanks for the pointer! I'll leave this answer here since I think `itertools.zip_longest` is still worth mentioning, but agree that this comment (and the other answer) are better solutions.

Comment: (I'm out of comment upvotes for the day, otherwise I'd vote on yours.)

Comment: Nice words are worth more than upvotes anyway! FWIW you don't neep zip_longest here as openpyxl treats all rows and columns the same in any specific worksheet.

Comment: It's still a nice tool to have when trying to zip two iterables of different lengths. Clearly I haven't used openpyxl much :-).

Comment: Of course, it's a great tool to have and spreadsheet sizes are "difficult" at the best of times, something that people love to complain about… but it, in general, consistency is best.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was working on a program to read the excel file using python and the library, openpyxl. I had very specific requirement to read the .xlsx file and to store the values in to the postgresql. I tried to google around the solution but all the solution that I read were only partly helpful. I am uploading the entire solution which worked to me like charm and incase anyone is looking for the similar solution.

```
import psycopg2 as db
import pyodbc
import openpyxl as xl


def create_table():
    excelfile = xl.load_workbook(<location of .xlsx file>)

worksheet = excelfile[<worksheet which I wanted to read>]
# connect to the postgres database
# getting the connection object
connection = db.connect(database="postgres", user=<username>, password=<password>, host="localhost")
# creating the cursor object
cursor = connection.cursor()
# create table
drop_table_query = "<Drop table query in case table already exists>"

create_table_query = "<Create table query>"
insert_query = "<Insert query>"
try:
    cursor.execute(drop_table_query)
    cursor.execute(create_table_query)
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
    pass

rows = worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=worksheet.max_row, values_only=True)

# iterate over rows and assign values to the table variables
for r in rows:
    value1 = r[0]
    value2 = r[1]
    value3 = r[2]
    value4 = r[3]
    value5 = r[4]
    value6 = r[5]
    value7 = r[6]
    value8 = r[7]

    datavalues = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8)

cursor.execute(insert_query, datavalues)
print("Operation Completed")
connection.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
```